# JavaFX; Eclipse points error at main method

Tags: java, javafx

I was trying to learn JavaFX and used the code on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLkOX4Eez6o.
I have Google it but could not find a solution.
Then Eclipse IDE shows this error: [image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Testes extends Application{

    Button botao;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Controle de processos");

        botao = new Button();
        botao.setText("+");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(botao);

        Scene cena = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(cena);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have saved the file and cleaned/rebuilt it. Doesn't seem like there is anything wrong to me...

Comment: compile the file with `javac Testes.java`. Seems like en eclipse issue

Comment: Do you declare your own module? If you don't require the correct modules, this could result in those issues.

Comment: I don't know how to declare my modules. Can you help?